# Python if elif code

Tags: python, if-statement

```
dummy = 10
os.system("cls")
x = input("""You use your attack by chossing a attack,for now you have 3 attacks.
Choose one:
1)punch 3dmg
2)use knife 4dmg
3)use pistol 6dmg
""")
if x == 1:
    dummy = dummy-3
    print"Dummies life:"+str(dummy)
elif x == 2:
    dummy = dummy-4
    print"Dummies life:"+str(dummy)
elif x == 3:
    dummy = dummy-6
    print"Dummies life:"+str(dummy)

x=raw_input("""Attack:
1)punch 3dmg
2)use knife 4dmg
3)use pistol 6dmg
""")

if x == 1:
    dummy = dummy-3
    print"Dummies life:"+str(dummy)
elif x == 2:
    dummy = dummy-4
    print"Dummies life:"+str(dummy)
elif x == 3:
    dummy = dummy-6
    print"Dummies life:"+str(dummy)
if dummy <= 0:
    os.system("cls")
elif dummy >= 0:
    os.system("cls")

    x=raw_input("Finish him write 1,2,3:")
#this is always printing help me#
    if x==1:
        dummy=dymmy-3
    elif x==2:
        dummy=dummy-4
    elif x==3:
        dummy=dummy-6
print"Good job!!!"
```

Why is it always printing the last if elif code ?
Sorry about the huge code I don't know if its maybe a mistake in the other parts of the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `input()` function takes string input.

Either convert the input into int using `int()` function

OR

```
if x == '1':
    # your stuffs

elif x == '2':
   # your stuffs
```

The problem is your last condition: `elif >=0` because no matter which integer I type it's always greater than 0 isn't it? Thus, it's calling the the last condition. Review and apply your logic correctly.

Comment: He is probably using 2.7,so input() do evaluate the values you enter.So he doen't need to convert them to int.raw_input() in 2.7 cause that problem.

Comment: Oh I thought he was using `Python3`. Which version of Python are you using @gamesyay12?

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input()` function reads a line from input (i.e. the user) and returns a string by stripping a trailing newline.

So `int == str` is always false.

Answer (score 1):

I can't downvote this question but it's terrible. I'm not really sure what you're writing. If I did punch twice I get your first condition, if I break the 10 mark on damage I get the other. Seems to work.

Might want to change dummy=dymmy-3 to dummy=dummy-3 in your last condition.

Also, put your comments above or inline with the code it's about to execute not under it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use raw_input to get the value for the second if/elif set, which returns a string, when you want an integer. Using input instead (like you did on your first if/elif set) will return an integer, which can be compared to integers like you try to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your game doesn't make too much sense even if it worked.

For example what if someone enters 3 times the first option?Dummy still lives and you will grant him a "GOOD JOB"

Does it have to play the games exactly 3 times?He can win it with 2-4 plays,depending on the choices.If not why don't you use a while loop until dummy is dead?

As the others above said,the problem is the the raw_input that assigns everything to a string,so input as integers,are assigned as strings and the if conditions cann't be checked.

But you can get this working with your assuming level of knowledge in python with 1/3 of that code with a while loop.

Comment: Vaggelas im not done there will be uses...It would be too easy if it was like thath this is just  the starter script

Comment: Ok,i don't really know what you are trying to do,i am saying that as a game doen't make that much sense.I got it working in 20 lines,in a similar way with a while loop,but you can stick with your way if it suits the later project.Replace the raw_input() with input() and the code will run ok, and also you don't really have to have 6 prints with the dummy's life.Remove them and put a simple print at the end of each play.You have 4 more lines than you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for the help guys :).I made a stupid mistake I just needed to change
     raw_input
into
     input
Sorry I now know more I  starrted then :(